# After deploying on /users/edit with devise gem — "The page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Please, help me.
After deploying my RoR project with capistrano I can't get to `/users/edit`. App returns me — "The page you were looking for doesn't exist". But on local machine everything works properly.

This is an error in production.log file:

`Started GET "/users/edit" for 77.91.198.139 at 2013-05-26 13:37:11 +0000 Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uVPb8V4QvWF/ix9PJevsqz9bCS6T5Fu2WftfHbvvUGw="} Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (11.9ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/equipment"}): app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:31:in _app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___743278238_83612130'`

Comment: You need to give code samples and your error in your production log file

Comment: I saw some interesting thing, whan i trying to login with another account, everything works.

Comment: this is an errors in production.log file `Started GET "/users/edit" for 77.91.198.139 at 2013-05-26 13:37:11 +0000
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"uVPb8V4QvWF/ix9PJevsqz9bCS6T5Fu2WftfHbvvUGw="}
  Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (11.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"devise/equipment"}):
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:31:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___743278238_83612130'`

Comment: please update your question with this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in your production log.

Comment: Thnx, I see this line `No route matches {:controller=>"devise/equipment"})` — because i used this code in my app `link_to "Equipment", controller: "equipment"` and this doesn't works properly in users/edit

Comment: Add a route for it in your `config/routes.rb` file instead of using controller option